# Functions in Namespace Not Attaching Event Listeners to HTML Elements

Tags: javascript, namespaces, dom-events

I have a local page to help in HTML and JavaScript that helps me with some basic tasks at work.  I've been going back over my code and rewriting it to use best practices, since it helps me learn, and recently I've been trying to study namespacing and put it to use by rewriting the common page functions and event listeners.

```
window.onload = (function() {
var automationPageWrapper = (function() {
    var self = {}

    self.evntListeners = {
        btnTextChange: function() {
            // Code that changes button text when clicked
            },
        btnColorChange: function(formID) {
            //  Code that iterates through buttons with a certain name
            //  and makes them all the same default color
            }
         }
     self.listeners = {
         btnListeners: function() {
             //  Add all event listeners having to do with buttons here
             }
         }
    return self;
    });
automationPageWrapper.listeners.btnListeners();
});
```

1. Why isn't this attaching the event listeners?
2. Is there a better way to be formatting/calling this?
3. Is this a professional method for setting up JavaScript code?

I tested the event listeners by taking the functions and posting them into the Chrome console, so I think they work.

The full text, since some people like reading through all of it:

```
  //  Global namespace for the Page Functions
window.addEventListener("onload", function() {
var automationPageWrapper = (function() {
var self = {};
  //  Namespace for event listeners
    self.evtListeners = {
          //  Function to change the color of a selected button
            btnColorChange: function(formName) {
                var elementsByName = document.getElementsByName(formName);

                for (var i = 0; i < elementsByName.length; i++) {
                        if (elementsByName[i].className == "active") {
                              elementsByName[i].className = "inactive";
                                break;
                            }
                    }

            },


          //  Add the event listeners
        listeners: {

                btnListeners: (function () {
                    document.getElementById('sidebar').addEventListener("click", function(e){
                            self.evtListeners.btnColorChange('sidebuttons');
                            e.target.className = "active";
                        });
                    })()

            }

}

return self;
})();

automationPageWrapper.listeners.btnColorChange();
});
```

Comment: Please show the actual code exactly as it is in the form where it does not work.  You've shown us the calling structure of what doesn't work, but not the whole actual code that doesn't work.  You're obviously doing something wrong.  We can only identify what if you show us the actual code.  Personally, I don't see why you're making your code this complicated.

Comment: Edited.  My last code review was "keep it to the point so people can read it."  And, it's complicated because I need to know how the complicated stuff works.  If I keep everything simple, I'll never find out how to keep the global scope clean, or how to format the structure so it can be properly documented and maintained.

Comment: You don't need to make code complicated in order to be maintainable and keep the global scope clean.  In fact, complicated code is much HARDER to maintain.  Your code should be a simple as possible that meets the objectives of the project and meets good standards of code design.  You seem to think that complicated structures are somehow better.  That is only true if the complication serves a very important objective and there is not a simpler way that also serves that objective.  Your code is very hard to follow and understand.   This is not the right direction.